# Cray CX1 nodes crashing when using mpi

Tags: windows, mpi

I'm wondering if anyone has experience using a CRAY CX1 when running MPI? When I'm running my code (which is MCNP - > https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_N-Particle_Transport_Code) I get intermittent crashes on my nodes.  My CX1 consists of 8 blades or nodes (running Window HPC 2008 R2) and they crash intermittently.  Sometimes they restart on their own and other times they won't restart at all and give me an error like `CPU 00/cnhannel01/Dimm00 unexpected error`  I've tried replacing the ram and it doesn't seem to help.

Here is the command I use to run my files using a batch file.

```
c:\mpich2\bin\mpiexec.exe -hosts 8 HEADNODE 8 CRAYNODE02 8 CRAYNODE03 8 CRAYNODE04 8 CRAYNODE05 8 CRAYNODE06 8 CRAYNODE07 8 CRAYNODE08 8 \\HEADNODE\USERS\administrator\desktop\win64mpi\bin\mcnpx.exe i=\\headnode\users\9m100122 n=\\headnode\users\9m100122.
```

I have basic knowledge when it comes to MPI and have looked on the net and have found very little information with regards to this problem.

Comment: I would say, you should contact Cray's support team.